# Image upload cfm or cfc for Redactor editor

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, redactor

I'm trying to configure redactor for ColdFusion with a simple image upload script.  The image doesn't actually upload to the server and I don't know how to get the variables back to ColdFusion for use by redactor. I can't seem to get [their sample code](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/upload-images/) converted properly to ColdFusion .

My call to the function is here:

```
this.article_content.redactor({ focus: true,
                        buttons: [  'html', '|', 'formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', '|', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', '|',
                                'image', 'video', 'file', 'link', '|',
                                'fontcolor', '|', 'alignment', '|', 'horizontalrule', 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'justify'],
                        imageUpload: 'lib/modules/imageUpload.cfm'
                    });
```

imageUpload.cfm

```
<cfparam name="form.file" default="">
<cffile action="upload" destination="#dir#"  accept="image/*"  nameconflict="overwrite" filefield="file"/>
<cfset result = structnew()>
<cfset result["name"] = cffile.serverFile>
<cfset result["url"] = cffile.serverFile>
<cfset result["filelink"] = cffile.serverFile>
<cfset result["type"] = cffile.ContentType &"/"& cffile.ContentSubType>
<cfset result["size"] = cffile.FileSize>

<cfreturn serializejson(result)>
```

Should this be a cfm page or a cfc page?  I basically just need to convert the serverFile variable to a json object that looks like this:

```
{ "url": "/images/img.jpg", "id": "123" }
```

Comment: What happens when you call this function?

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a question. What doesn't work for you? Are you using `cffile action="upload"`? What does your `imageUpload.cfm` look like?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  Question edited to include my imageUpload.cfm code.  The image doesn't actually upload to the server and I don't know how to get the variables back to coldfusion for use by redactor.  Thanks.

Comment: I learned that redactor existed by reading this question so I have no knowledge of how it works.  However, it appears that the code is creating an html form.  I wouldn't, however, expect an image to be uploaded until the user selects an image and submits that form.

Comment: Redactor's file name is "file" and the id is "redactor_file".  I guess I just need to write a cfm or cfc that would return the json variables  back to redactor for use (as shown in their example)

Comment: Right now, your `imageUpload.cfm` has a `cfreturn` tag, which won't do anything outside a function. You'd need to change this to `<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(result)#</cfoutput>`. For the file not uploading to the server, what do your browser debug tools say? (e.g. FireBug) Any errors? does it record a response from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were very close! This should do the trick for you:

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true">
<!---
Your location to upload files to
Ideally this would be outside the webroot so you can upload the file, check 
to ensure it's not malicious, then move it to a publicly accessible location
--->
<cfset relativePath = "uploads/">
<cfset dir = expandPath(relativePath)>

<cfset result = {}>

<cfif structKeyExists(form, "file")>

    <cffile action="upload" destination="#dir#" accept="image/*"  nameconflict="overwrite" filefield="file">

    <cfset result["name"] = cffile.serverFile>
    <cfset result["url"] = relativePath&cffile.serverFile>
    <cfset result["filelink"] = cffile.serverFile>
    <cfset result["type"] = cffile.ContentType&"/"&cffile.ContentSubType>
    <cfset result["size"] = cffile.FileSize>

<cfelse>
    <cfset result["error"] = "no file uploaded">
</cfif>

<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
<cfoutput>#serializejson(result)#</cfoutput>
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="false">
```

The main difference is that with a .cfm page you can just output the JSON, you were trying to return it (with cfreturn) which is what you'd do from a function.

For good measure I've added the `enablecfoutputonly` setting to ensure you don't get any unwanted whitespace which would break the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `cfheader` with content type `application/json`. And as @beloitdavisja suggested replace `cfreturn` with `cfoutput`. You don't use `cfreturn` in cfm page except when you are inside a function. Like this:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
<cfoutput>#serializejson(result)#</cfoutput>
```